# Tamaño de un arreglo de caracteres con una variable en C

Tags: c

Lo que deseo es utilizar una variable para indicar el tamaño de un arreglo de caracteres, por ejemplo:

```
int size = 10;
char vector[size];
```

Recibo el error:

> "Expression must have a constant value".

¿Qué puedo hacer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esto ocurre porque en C (y en algunos compiladores de C++) los arrays deben tener un tamaño que sea constante y conocido en el momento de compilar. Sé que estás definiendo unas variables y que debería ser obvio para el compilador que el tamaño está fijado en 10, pero el compilador no sabe si esa variable va a ser modificada y no puede asumir que es una constante (es una variable al fin y al cabo).

La solución sería definir size como constante usando la palabra reservada `const` y entonces ya no debería aparecer ese error:

```
const int size = 10;
char vector[size];
```

Nota- No he podido comprobar que el código de arriba sea correcto porque mi compilador (de C++) compila sin ningún tipo de errores tu código original (y el de esta respuesta también)

---

Alternativamente podrías intentar reservar la memoria con `malloc`, para ello el código sería algo como esto:

```
int size = 10;
char *vector;

vector = (char *) malloc (sizeof(char) * size);
```

Y no te olvides de hacer un `free(vector)` al final para liberar la memoria que reservaste con el `malloc` o la aplicación tendrá pérdidas de memoria.

Comment: Estoy usando Visual Studio, pero compilando como C. Tengo entendido que esto no funciona es después de C99. Ahora, creo que tu alternativa me puede servir, mas me preocupa que en realidad estoy es programando con la API de Windows y no tengo cómo hacer constante la variable que necesito para el arreglo, pues la devuelve una función. ¿Habría alternativa con `malloc`?

Comment: Claro. Deja y edito cómo se podría reservar memoria con `malloc`

Comment: Muchas gracias, Álvaro. Probaré con las funciones de la API y si algo abro otro hilo más específico.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro "*Esto ocurre porque en C (y en algunas versiones de C++) los arrays deben tener un tamaño que sea constante y conocido en el momento de compilar*" esa afirmación no es del todo correcta. Todos los arrays estáticos de C++ deben tener un tamaño conocido en tiempo de compilación según el estándar; después hay **extensiones de compilador** que permiten arrays de longitud variable, así pues "y en algunas versiones de C++" debería ser "y en algunos compiladores de C++".

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Gracias por el comentario. Actualicé la respuesta con lo que dijiste

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro gracias a ti por tu excelente respuesta :) dejo aquí [información sobre arrays de tamaño variable (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) para futuras referencias.

Answer (score 2):

Con el standard C90 no puedes declarar arrays cuyo tamaño sea especificado por una variable.

```
int main(void)
{
  int tam;
  tam =  7;
  char vector[tam];
  return 0;
}
```

Al compilar el código anterior nos da un error :

```
jose@ordenador ~/t $ gcc --std=c90 --pedantic -o a a.c
a.c: En la función ‘main’:
a.c:5:3: aviso: ISO C90 prohíbe la matriz de longitud variable ‘vector’ [-Wvla]
   char vector[tam];
   ^
a.c:5:3: aviso: ISO C90 prohíbe mezclar declaraciones y código [-Wpedantic]
```

Pero el standard C99 sí lo permite. El código compila sin problemas al especificar ese standard.

```
jose@ordenador ~/t $ gcc --std=c99 --pedantic -o a a.c
```

Con lo que puedes usar ese código sin problemas. Es totalmente portable y no depende de la API de Windows. Salvo que te veas obligado a usar un compilador que no soporte C99, pero eso es altamente improbable.